# I have tried to make code for inbuild javascript function (touppercase).Does this helpfull or not?

Tags: javascript, function, toupper

This code is basically use as a inbuilt fuction of javascript touppercase shortformat which would be benificial for interview .sometimes we need not to use inbuilt functions ..so there is code for them.

```
    //change lower case to upper case
    function Change_Upper_Case() {
    var a1 = [], a6 = [], i = 0; // define all variables
    a1 = document.getElementById('EnterString').value; //get value which is    enter by you
    while(i < a1.length) { //check condition is true or false
        var a2 = a1[i]; 
       var a3 = a2.charCodeAt(0); //get ASCII value of char in number format
       var a5 = a2;
   if(a3 >= 97 && a3 < 123) { // a = 97 and z=122
    var a4 = a3-32;
    a5 = String.fromCharCode(a4); //change ASCII value of a4 in char format
    }
    a6[i] = a5;
    i++;
    }
    document.getElementById('ShowString').innerHTML = a6.join(''); //print input String on your browser  
}
```

```js
   

 //change lower case to upper case
    function Change_Upper_Case() {
     var a1 = [], a6 = [], i = 0; // define all variables
     a1 = document.getElementById('EnterString').value; //get value which is enter by you
    while(i < a1.length) { //check condition is true or false
     var a2 = a1[i]; 
     var a3 = a2.charCodeAt(0); //get ASCII value of char in number format
     var a5 = a2;
    if(a3 >= 97 && a3 < 123) { // a = 97 and z=122
     var a4 = a3-32;
     a5 = String.fromCharCode(a4); //change ASCII value of a4 in char format
     }
     a6[i] = a5;
     i++;
     }
     document.getElementById('ShowString').innerHTML = a6.join(''); //print input String on your browser  
    }
```

```html
   

 <input type="text" id="EnterString"/>
    <input type="button" value="Upper Case" onclick="Change_Upper_Case()"/>
    <span id="ShowString"></span><br/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for this input: "Здравствуйте". Stack Overflow isn't a blog. Your question has to be phrased in the form of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript already has a toUpperCase function for the string types, take a look http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp